# Почему handleClick не видит аттрибуты? (codesandbox)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Код
***https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-tbdpg***
Так же, ругается на ключи, хотя ключи я указал

Comment: Код (минимально достаточный для воспроизведения проблемы) должен быть прямо в вопросе, а не по внешней ссылке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleClick` видит атрибуты всех  `DOM` элементов если атрибуты есть в этих элементах в `DOM`.

В вашем случае в ищете атрибут `key` который использует сам React (`key`).React не добавляет этот атрибут в дом этот атрибут нужен для сравнение виртуального `DOM`-а с browser `DOM` и не больше.

Во вторых про ключей который вы добавили.

Ключи добавляется в родительский элемент внутри цикла а не в дочерный как вы написали потому и ругается.

```
handleClick = e => {
    const elemId = e.target.getAttribute("tabindex");
    console.log(elemId);
};

render() {
    const { users } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <List className={classes.root}>
        {users.map(user => (
          <Fragment key={user.id}>
            <ListItem>
              <ListItemAvatar>
                <Avatar>
                  <PersonIcon />
                </Avatar>
              </ListItemAvatar>
              {/* {console.log(user.id)} */}
              <ListItemText primary={user.name} />
              <IconButton
                onClick={this.handleClick}
                key={user.id}
                edge="end"
                aria-label="delete"
              >
                <DeleteIcon />
              </IconButton>
            </ListItem>
            <Divider />
          </Fragment>
        ))}
      </List>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Да, проверил DOM, там нет его.

Comment: @AlexFlow можно добавить `custom data` свойство (к примеру `data-elementId`)  и читать от туда.Если вопрос решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку.

Comment: А почему e.target не выводит текущий компонент React, а e.currentTarget выводит?

Comment: @AlexFlow Ну потому что `target` это елемент который вызвал события (event)  а `currentTarget` это елемент к которому был добавлен event listener.

Comment: И получается, соответственно в моем случае вызывает событие вызывается в svg иконке, а listener цепляется уже на кнопку? Это именно из-за библиотеки так?

Comment: @AlexFlow `IconButton` это один целый компонент внутри него уже есть `svg` и кликая на 
 `svg` вы также кликаете весь компонент.По другому не знаю уже как объяснить.И я только сейчас заметил у вас async перед componentDidMount уже второй раз тут вижу такой код.И мой вам совет НЕ ПИШИТЕ ТАК БОЛЬШЕ НИКОГДА.Прочтите про жизненных циклов React очень внимательно.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ